# How to put "li" on top of "ul" when overflow enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul` which has CSS property `overflow : auto`.

Now, at a certain point, each `li` gets highlighted one at a time, based on some user interaction. I would like to put the currently highlighted `li` at the top of the scroll window, if that is possible.

I have looked into the jQuery `scrollTo` function, but I don't think that would work here or maybe I am unable to get it working here.

Any other way I can achieve this functionality?

Here is some updated code.

```
function next_song() {
    if (song_counter == playlist.length - 1) {
        song_counter = 0;
    } else {
        song_counter++;
    }
    var audio = $("#audio");
    var myLi = document.getElementById('play_list').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < (myLi.length); i++) {
        myLi[i].style.background = "none";
        myLi[i].style.color = "white";
    }
    $("li").eq(song_counter).css("background", "white");
    $("li").eq(song_counter).css("color", "black");
    nowplaying.innerHTML = song_list[song_counter];
    $("#mp3source").attr("src", playlist[song_counter]);
    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();
}
```

As can be seen, I am highlighting a particular `li` element which may or may not be visible inside the scroll window. I'd like to get scroll the `ul` element till this particular `li` element is in view.

Comment: please provide some relevant code

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You want to show Element that overflow to its parent? Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use native `scrollIntoView()` method:

```
$('.highlighted').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

If not what you are looking for, consider to improve question.

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPDzk/show/)

Comment: Damn good answer. :D
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to make the scrolling in a div and not the ul element:

```
var topPosition = $("#liId").position().top;
$('#scrollingDiv').scrollTop(topPosition);
```

here is a working code using scrollTop that you can play with and use (Its not the optimal code though): 
http://jsfiddle.net/pJLK8